# Finding the limit of $f(f(x))$ type problem

Tags: limits

Let $f$ be a differentiable function and equation
of normal to the graph of $y = f(x)$ at $x = 3$ is
$3y = x + 18$. If $L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{f\left( {3 + {{\left( {4{{\tan }^{ - 1}}x - \pi } \right)}^2}} \right) - f\left( {{{\left( {3 + f\left( 3 \right) - x - 6} \right)}^2}} \right)}}{{{{\sin }^2}\left( {x - 1} \right)}}$ then find the value of L.

My approach is as follow

$y = \frac{{x + 18}}{3} \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = \frac{{x + 18}}{3}$

$f'\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{3}$

Confused after applyying L.Hosp rule
$L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{{f'\left( {3 + {{\left( {4{{\tan }^{ - 1}}x - \pi } \right)}^2}} \right) \times 2\left( {4{{\tan }^{ - 1}}x - \pi } \right) \times \frac{4}{{1 + {x^2}}} - f'\left( {{{\left( {3 + f\left( 3 \right) - x - 6} \right)}^2}} \right) \times 2\left( {3 + f\left( 3 \right) - x - 6} \right) \times  - 1}}{{\sin 2\left( {x - 1} \right)}}$

Comment: As written, the limit you have doesn't exist because it approaches $$\frac{f(3)-f(9)}{0}$$ which is not L'Hopitalable

Comment: @NinadMunshi It is not $f(9)$ in the numerator.

Comment: @AnuragA Check again. What exactly is $(3+7-1-6)^2$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi you are right, I missed the square in the expression.

Comment: @AnuragA I wouldn't worry about it too much. It's most likely a typo for $3+(f(3)-x-6)^2$ or something similar as we suspect.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Normal $3y=x+18$ gives us $y=7$ for $x=3$ so it intersects the curve at $(3,7)$ so $f(3)=7$ and the slope of the normal is $\frac{1}{3}$, so $f'(3)=-3$ (normal being perpendicular to the tangent etc.).

Comment: This post only addresses a minor technical detail in the problem as opposed to techniques for the actual limit. I feel this would be more suited for comment than an answer, unless you would like to flesh it out.

Comment: @NinadMunshi It is meant as a hint as OP seems to have an issue with identifying the values of the function and the derivative. If OP needs further clarification then OP can ask for the same.